# ANTLR4: Generated lexer does not return tokens

Tags: c++, mysql, antlr, antlr4

I want to use antlr generated lexer and parser in a c++ project to parse MySQL queries. I'm using [Positive Technologies grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/sql/mysql/Positive-Technologies).
I have read some tutorials and believe I should create an input stream, which will be used to create the lexer. And the lexer should then generate tokens that can be used with the parser. However, when I run the code below I get a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)" error. The debugger shows that the lexer does not hold any tokens. How can I fix this?

```
void parse(std::string usr_query) {
    using namespace antlr4;
    using namespace std::string_literals;
    std::transform(usr_query.begin(), usr_query.end(), usr_query.begin(), ::toupper);
    
    ANTLRInputStream input(usr_query);
    smallMySQLLexer lexer(&input);

    CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);
    tokens.fill();
    ...
```

For Reference: Runtime and tool are both pulled from https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/master

EDIT:

- I could not use the released antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar or antlr-4.9.3-complete.jar, because it would throw errors with any runtime I found (prebuilt [version](https://www.antlr.org/download.html), and built locally following these [instructions](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/tree/dev/runtime/Cpp)).
- I just took back all changes I made to the original grammar to see if I messed it up. Now, only the name is modified, not the actual content.
- The lexer has worked before with that code.

Comment: Your code using the unmodified grammars-v4/sql/mysql/Positive-Technologies/ grammar works fine for me using 4.9.3. You might want to use strict 4.9.3 and go back to the unmodified grammar first. See the templates [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/_scripts/templates/Cpp).

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. Let me edit my question for further info. I would love to run the test scripts, but I can't get this to work for MacOS.

Comment: Getting the devel env straightened out is not easy (it's a mess). I use openjdk 11.0.13, GNU C++ 9.3, CMake 3.16.3, Dotnet 6.0.101, but then, I'm on Linux, and I haven't set up the CI for grammars-v4 to work on MacOS. BTW, the Antlr complete .jar file for 4.9.3 requires https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/commit/e4c1a74 runtime, not current "master", and compiled with C++17 or C++20. They don't tell you that in the instructions.

Comment: The latest downloadable runtime and the latest downloadable antlr4 tool should work together. I haven't heard anything that tells a different story. Also, give us the exact error you get.

Comment: @kaby76 Thank you, I got it to work using the commit-tag.